# Columnstore index and bit columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table with almost 1T rows.

```
create table bigtable (
  K1 int, K2 date, -- PK columns
  C1 ..., C8 ...., -- columns with various data types like float, date, varchar, ...
  B1 bit, B2 bit, ......, B10 bit -- 10 or so bit columns
  primary key (K1, K2)
)
```

I want to use columnstore to increase the query performance. Which of the following options is best for select queries? Don't worry about insert/update.

1. Create a cluster columnstore index
2. Create a noncluster columnstore index for all the columns
3. Create a noncluster columnstore index for all the columns except these bit columns (maybe other low selective columns too?)

Comment: You should start from exact queries you got to implement. And probably rethink your pk.

Comment: This is something that you will need to test yourself with queries that are representative of the workload that you will be running

Comment: The users will write queries themselves. A lot of the queries will be aggregation queries.